# Android handler: Handler does not work as expected

Tags: android, handler

I have a button name **btnOk**, inside this button I have a normal method.

My idea is that after an interval of time, the method inside this button will be executed automatically.

So I create an **Handler** to delay my function. I expected the programming working like this:

Here are the logic:

> User can click the button Ok => After 20s, if user does not click the
>   button => Run the Method

My prolem is that 20s is calculated as total for every time I run this itent.

For examle:

1. From activity A, I start B (the OK button is in B, user must click button in 20s),
2. First time, **it takes only 15s for user decides to click the buton.**
3. After that, I start Activity A (like a loop A => B => A => B...);
4. And again, from activity A to B, **this time I expected method must run after 20s, but only 5s later** (I guess that 15s for 1st time + 5s after start 2nd time will be counted as total 20s), It executed automatically.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   //Do something
   value();

   //Create handler
   final Handler handler = new Handler();

   //Run method automatically after 20s
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
           submitResult();
       }
   }, 20000);

   //Wait for user clicks, 
   //must start in 20s or submitResult(); will be executed automatically
   btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           submitResult();
       }
    });


   }
   ```

Can any one help me figure out the problem? Or any way to **auto onclick after an interval of time**?

I Really appreciate your helps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the first `Handler` running, not the new one (created in the second activity B). If the user clicks the button, you should "cancel" the handler, otherwise it will run `submitResult()` twice.

Try this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(null);
    submitResult();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still does not working as my prolem. :(

Comment: @ManhNguyenVan make sure you added that line to the `OnClickListener`. This should do it unless there is something else going on there.

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed the implementation so it now work perfectly. I must say thank you for your idea, instead using the handler, I implement countdown timer, after calling the timer, inside the OnClickListener, I call myTimer.cancel() to stop the timer. It wok like a charm.

Thank yout again my bro!